# Two interface declarations in one file

Tags: iphone, xcode, cocoa-touch, linker-errors

Here is my .h file:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface ShareOfflineItem : NSObject
@property (strong, nonatomic) id shareService;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *title, *url;
@end

@interface ShareOfflineQueue : NSObject
+(ShareOfflineQueue *)sharedQueue;
-(void)addItemToQueue:(ShareOfflineItem *) item;
-(void)flushQueue;
-(void)saveQueueToDisk;

@end
```

As you can see nothing more special. But when I import my .h file and try to instantiate ShareOfflineItem I get a linking error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ShareOfflineItem", referenced from:
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Why not put them under a single definition?

Answer (score -1):

Use

```
@class ShareOfflineItem;
@class ShareOfflineQueue;
```

after the import. This might help.